# Printing face attributes for mode-line and mode-line-inactive

Tags: faces

How can I print the face attributes for `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`?

Comment: `M-x describe-face`

Comment: What is the face name for `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`?

Comment: `mode-line` and `mode-line-incative` are face names. Just do `M-x describe-face RET mode-line RET`.

Comment: You can also list and modify faces using `M-x customize-group` `mode-line-faces`, and you can list all faces using `list-faces-display` (and/or the enhanced versions provided by the alternative commands in different completion frameworks like [counsel](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), helm etc.)